# Beginner at PHP - Where clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Im very new to php and would like to know if my where clause is correct, i think that im missing something in my where clause. please see below:

```
<?php
$val1 = $_SESSION['dbase_user']['id'];

$gen = "SELECT gender FROM tbl_users WHERE id = $val1";
$result1 = dbQuery($gen);
$row1 = dbFetchAssoc($result1);
?>

<tr>
<td width="180" height="30" class="label"><strong>Gender</strong></td>
<td height="30" class="content">
<input type="text" class="frmInputs" size="10" value="<?php echo strtoupper($row1['gender']) ?>" disabled="disabled"/></td>
</tr>
```

The output: It always gets the first gender of the 1st row in the database.

The Question: I wanted it to point to other records based on my where clause.

Notes and tried scenario:

1. Id is the primary key in my DB <--- ID is int
2. i also tried using `WHERE fname = $val1` <-- this is a string

Many many thanks!

Comment: Since you're beginning, you should learn proper habits now, instead of learning the old way and having to unlearn them. So read about prepared queries with mysqli or PDO, instead of substituting variables into queries.

Comment: But other than that, I don't see any problem with your WHERE clause that would cause it to return the wrong row. It should return the gender of the user with the given ID.

Comment: For the string, you need to put quotes around it: `WHERE fname = '$val1'`.

Comment: woaw! amazing! it works like a charm! lesson learned you should be very keen on this characters. thank u thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work correctly when `$val1` is a number.

When it's a string, you need to put quotes around it in the SQL.

```
$gen = "SELECT gender FROM tbl_users WHERE fname = '$val1'";
```

But it would be best if you use a database API that supports prepared queries, either MySQLI or PDO. Then you don't have to worry about this at all.